# How to correctly override equals for Hibernate entity with @NaturalId

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, kotlin

Many times already discussed how to redefine equals/hashCode for Entity.

My question is about the need to use all the fields in equals.
Consider two cases.

When we use all fields for equals:

```
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NaturalId
    @Column(name = "isbn", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String isbn;

    @Column
    private String name;

    private Book() {
    }

    public Book(String isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Book book = (Book) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, book.id) &&
                Objects.equals(isbn, book.isbn) &&
                Objects.equals(name, book.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(isbn);
    }
}
```

And test:

```
public class BookTest1 {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;

    @Test
    public void fromTransientToManageSameEntity() {
        Book book1 = new Book("4567-5445-5434-3212");
        Book book2 = new Book("4567-5445-5434-3212");

        em.persist(book2);
        flushAndClean();

        assertThat(book1, is(not((equalTo(book2))))); // not equals
    }
}
```

As we see, when translating entities from a transient into a manage state - the same entities will not be equal.

Another case is when we use in equals only @NaturalId:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Book book = (Book) o;
    return Objects.equals(isbn, book.isbn);
}
```

And test:

```
public class BookTest2 {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;

    @Test
    public void fromTransientToManageSameEntity() {
        Book book1 = new Book("4567-5445-5434-3212");
        Book book2 = new Book("4567-5445-5434-3212");

        em.persist(book2);
        flushAndClean();

        assertThat(book1, equalTo(book2)); // equals
    }
}
```

As we see, now both entities will be equal.

My question is whether the same entity should be equal in the transition to manage state or not. And accordingly how to correctly redefine the equals in this situation.

Comment: Generally speaking, it's not a good idea to define equality for entities (as an "entity" is defined as a record that has an identity independent of its values). Why exactly are you wanting to do this?

Comment: @chrylis I have to do this for testing. Because I have to make sure that all the fields are correct.

Comment: Compare the fields individually, not by an aggregate `equals`.

Comment: @chrylis it's not cool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-implement-equals-hashcode-and-tostring-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) `equals` and `hashCode` should be state-agnostic. If you have overriden only the first one, it's bad and can cause strange bugs. They need to have a [contract](https://www.programcreek.com/2011/07/java-equals-and-hashcode-contract/).

The simplest way would be to use lombok - annotate your class with `@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true, callSuper = false)` and the fields used in comparison with `@EqualsAndHashCode.Include`.

Comment: i don't like lombok. So which of the two tests is correct? BookTest1 or BookTest2?

Comment: I am interested in a more global question, whether there should be an equal entity during the transition to a manage state

Comment: Actually there is no right answer, this depends on you. In my opinion, there should be an equality, please, refer to the article for in-depth discussion.

Comment: Also bear in mind, that `hashCode` should be also overriden.

Comment: Basically it depends on your needs. Ask yourself a question - Do you compare entities with transient objects and use mixed hash-based collections and maps?

Comment: I'm just used to adding all fields to equals, which is especially critical for tests. And the option is closer to me - when should not be equal, since the entity has moved to a new state.

Comment: for hash-based collections - there are no problems here, because hashCode does not change

Answer (score 1):

When I looked into this a while ago, I concluded that there's no single right answer.

I ended up checking *only* the `@Id` property in `equals()` and `hashCode()`, as that seemed to behave best.  (We don't use any `@NaturalId`s; it could work with that instead, but it may be safer to stick with the `@Id`.)

I think the only potential issue I found with that was if a new instance gets added to a collection before being persisted.  In practice, that never happens in our project, and so it works well.  (If it does in your project, you may still find this the best trade-off, to avoid problems when *persisted* objects appear in collections, which is much more common.)

As other answers have pointed out, if you override `equals()` you *must* also override `hashCode()`, to ensure that equal objects always have the same hashcode.  (The question's first example does comply with this, though it's perhaps a little confusing for the two methods not to check all the same fields.)

In Kotlin, by the way, those two methods become manageably small:

```
override fun equals(other: Any?) = other === this
                                || (other is MyEntity && entityId == other.entityId)

override fun hashCode() = entityId
```

(Yet another example of why I love Kotlin!)